# Are There Any Working Dependencies for Tor/Orbot Library for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library, tor, orbot

I'm currently developing a kotlin webview/browser app for android. I wanted to use the tor/orbot library which doesn't require user to have tor/orbot app installed to use it via my browser. But, whenever I tried importing a correct **tor/Orbot** library for android, it doesn't work!  My Dependencies are as follow:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.protonvpn.android.sdk:vpn:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jehy:Tor-Onion-Proxy-Library:0.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'org.torproject:android-orchestra:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.micahflee:TorAndroid:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1' 
}
```

my import statements (last ones which i tried) :

```kotlin
import com.github.micahflee.torandroid.TorClient
import com.github.micahflee.torandroid.TorManager
```

**The Last Was Suggested by studio Bot in android studio**

Comment: You may want to have a look at this [library](https://guardianproject.info/code/tor-android/), maybe.

Comment: I tried those libraries too but It doesn't work .